# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. ElephantSQL postgres database

Tags: postgresql, driver

I am trying to connect my mobile application to an elephant SQL database. The error I am getting is this:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.

and below is my code in my database.java file I have a lot commented out that I have tried.

```java
try {
            //Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            //Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
            //System.out.printf("\n\n\n1: %s\n\n\n", drivers.nextElement().getClass().getName());
            //Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://temp.db.elephantsql.com:5432/";
            //System.out.printf("\n\n\n2: %s\n\n\n",DriverManager.getDriver(url).getClass().getName());
            String username = "redacted";
            String password = "redacted";
            //Properties props = new Properties();
            //props.setProperty("user", username);
            //props.setProperty("password", password);
            //props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
            /*
            String databaseUrl = "YOUR_DATABASE_URL";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);
            DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("JDBC Driver Name: " + metaData.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("JDBC Driver Version: " + metaData.getDriverVersion());
             */
            //Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(database_url);
            if (c == null) {
                throw new Exception("Error: DriverManager.getConnection() returned a null object");
            }
```

Here is my gradle.build on module level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.coachal2021"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1') with module('junit:junit:4.10')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation project(path: ':wahoo_fitness_android_api_1.8.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.1'
    testImplementation files('libs/postgresql-42.6.0.jar')
}
```

Here is my gradle.build on project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath files('libs/postgresql-42.6.0.jar')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My java version is 1.8 and the postgres driver in my module's build.gradle is 42.7.1.

Does anyone know what this may be? Most of the stuff I have seen is saying it's either an incorrect URL or the build.gradle doesn't contain the jdbc import, but mine has both.

I tried:

1. updating my `java implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'` to version 42.7.1
2. playing around with my url layout as explained on the elephantSQL documentation: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connecting-to-the-database
3. Including Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

I see in my build.gradle, the target SDK version is 30, but my SDK is higher than this. Could this be a problem>? if so how do I update my SDK version.

EDIT: spent the next several hours digging into this. Found that the postgres version I was using in my build.grade was not the right one. Apparently 42.2.9 is the only version with all the required methods. This fixed the above issue. But caused another one: “org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not find a java cryptographic algorithm: jks KeyStore not available.” of which I can find very little information on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.